# Create a service in a Linux Subsystem on Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, services

I installed correctly **WSL2**, I'm currently running **ubuntu subsystem** on **windows 10** and I would like to **create** a **service** to start a program **on startup**. The problem is that I cannot use systemctl because of this error :

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Do you know a way to solve this problem and use systemctl or do you have another way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

`systemd` is not enabled on `WSL` or `WSL2`although `systemd` files exist.

A bug report exists for this. See https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4202

There are a couple of workarounds. See https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script for one that does not need dotNET.